Trying to get forgiveness from someone we can't reach out to on Yom Kippur

On Yom Kippur, G‑d mercifully erases all the sins we have committed "before G‑d"—but not the sins we may have committed
against our fellow man.

There is this fellow Jewish child, whom I had wronged during my childhood, I don't have the opportunity to contact or communicate with him (ever again). I sincerely apologize for my actions and am deeply ashamed of my actions. I aspire to perform Teshuvah on his behalf. I will cease any wrongdoing towards my fellow Yidden and make a confession to Hashem, perform viduy, and offer tzedakhah.  I have read the following on Dinonline :
As a side point, the Vilna Gaon says that a person who wronged someone else, and can’t find the person, etc., should do whatever is in his ability to do to try to correct what was done, and when Hashem sees that the person tried the best they can, He will arrange it that the other half of the sin will get corrected also. Therefore, the person should do whatever humanly possible for them to do to get forgiveness, including davening, that the person should be mochel you. After that we hope that Hashem, in His unending kindness will arrange things so that the other person will be mochel.
Can we improve? Will Hashem arrange for the sin to be corrected?

This site is not for personal questions, sorry. Sounds like you have found an answer anyway? Vilna Ga'on knows what he is talking about.
